# Why does Eclipse create a Boolean object rather than a primitive type on "create local variable"?

Tags: java, eclipse, primitive-types

I just debugged code and saw a strange behavior of Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2). I've done something like

```
debug1 = aMethod();

private boolean aMethod() {(...)};
```

Of course the IDE gives a warning that debug1 can't be resolved to a variable and provides the quick fix "create local variable debug1". I use this very often if I have to debug code I'm not familiar with. I just can create a few debug variables without checking what the particular method returns.

However, I recognized that Eclipse changes the above code to

```
Boolean debug1 = aMethod();
```

So, it creates a Boolean-object variable rather than a primitive type. Shouldn't the object be the special case rather than the default behavior? Why is it the default behavior then?

Comment: Because in production, Boolean is used over boolean, simply because it allows a null value (unlike boolean which can only be true, false and "undeclared")

Comment: not so bad, IMO, since they're planning to remove primitive datatypes in a future version (rumoured 10) of Java

Comment: @NemanjaT but the return value can't be `null`. Why not make the variable type `Object` if you want to handle the possibility of values it can't be?

Comment: @NemanjaT That doesn't sound plausible to me. Why would one per default choose a more special case? It's like "I may need to assign null to a bool. Let's always use Boolean!" Doesn't sound really thought out :D

Comment: Try to do `boolean myVar = null;`, now imagine the declaration coming from a database, or some other outer source. It could be anything, or nothing. `Boolean` is more prepared for that than boolean is. By the way, the reason why eclipse throws you an error (while it shouldn't be) for declaring a boolean is because you (or someone) set it up that way. It's not a default behaviour.

Comment: *But it's not coming from a database*: it is coming from a method which returns `boolean`, which has 3 results: `true`, `false`, or throwing an exception. `null` isn't a possibility here.

Comment: @NemanjaT I think you misunderstood something. It doesn't show a warning for declaring a boolean. It shows a warning for not declaring anything (which is of course correct). Check out my given code example. And for the first part: yes, it makes sense in various cases, in "special cases" but you can't waste this space per default just because a Boolean is more prepared for a incoming database null, can you?

Comment: @Stultuske Project Valhalla is planned to allow primitive types for generics, not removing primitives types altogether.